# Best wiki for use on a LAN?

Tags: wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendation for Wiki that supports WYSIWYG?](https://superuser.com/questions/46134/recommendation-for-wiki-that-supports-wysiwyg)

There's alot of stuff out there but gets hideously unclear when you delve into details and all I want is something quite simple.

Basically I would like to set up a small intranet for 3-4 people.  It has to be on a LAN and no one will access it remotely.

It has to be simple but have the core features you would expect from a decent wiki including good permissions, data stored in text (so no database), will run on Windows and have WYSIWYG.  I'll want to refer to files on servers using mapped drives or UNC paths - would be nice to be able to browse to them.

Dokuwiki looked good but now I'm not so sure as set up for a LAN isn't specifically spelt out.  PMWiki is under consideration as well but I'm just not sure.

Ideally I'd just use Backpack because anyone can use that but that's hosted (we don't want our files stored in the cloud) and costs money.

Any suggestions for the least complicated approach?

Comment: Community wiki? There is no single answer for this...

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why being on a LAN differs from anything else if you choose a web based tool.
[Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) will work just fine.

All you have to do is set up some local hosting and sharing. You can do that pretty easily with [EasyPhp](http://www.easyphp.org/index.php) and then configure your firewall.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/).  It's text file-based, well-documented, and easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org). It's the only wiki that's **explicitly made to be used as business intranet.**

- WYSIWYG
- Easy setup, even a VMware instant server available (ideal for testing)
- Many plugins available
- Very flexible (allows any HTML if needed)
- Very mature (Foswiki is based on TWiki, 10 years development)
- Good documentation
- Good support
- Very good security measures: per-usergroup, per-user, per-page, etc.

The only downside in your case is that it's originally made to be run on Linux+Apache, not Windows, but [there's a package available for that](http://foswiki.org/Download/DownloadVirtualMachineImageRaw) as well! It's actually a virtual machine that is completely configured and ready to run. The above link is a page that explains all you need to know.